# C++ : global structure

Tags: c++, struct, global

In the same way than using global variable,

```
const double GRAVITY = 9.81;

int main(){}
```

I would like to use global structure

```
typedef struct {
    double gravity;
} WorldConfig;

WorldConfig WC;
WC.gravity = 9.81;

int main(){}
```

but this does not compile ("WC" does not name a type).

Is there a way to do this or alternatively, a good reason why using a global struct would be a super bad idea ?

thx

Comment: There's no difference between a scalar type and a class type as far as the design is concerned. Both are equally good or bad when used as global variables.

Comment: You can only do this `WC.gravity = 9.81;` inside a function. BTW any reason you cannot use one instance of `WorldConfig` in `main()`? Also, the `typedef struct` syntax is not needed in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *initialize* the global variable:

```
struct WorldConfig
{
    double gravity;
};

WorldConfig WC = { 9.82 };

int main() { }
```

Comment: thx, close to what I wanted to know ! Only issue is if WorldConfig has a lots of fields. Then such initialization would be error prone, as it would be easy to mixed up two values, no ?

Comment: Why does this solve the problem? I mean why does the compiler complain when it is done as the OP posted it? When we write `WorldConfig WC` before main, why won't it create a struct variable (like it does within a function) and allow `WC.gravity = 9.82` on the next line? [Please do post links if any, to help me with these]

Comment: @SuvP: You cannot have non-declaration statements at file scope in C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB . Thanks. Actually I thought even `WorldConfig WC` is not allowed at filescope.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you don't need the `typedef`, this is not C. Also, you need to set the `gravity` member in the initializer:

```
struct WorldConfig {
    double gravity;
} WC = {9.81};
```

However, for such constants, you probably want them to be *really* constant, so you could do:

```
struct WorldConfig
{
    static constexpr double gravity = 9.81; // requires C++11
};
```

Comment: Gravity is constant?! Maybe in *your* world :-) Oh, and that code doesn't work.

Comment: @KerrekSB it isn't really constant in any world that I know of :)

Comment: @MichaelWild: Still not correct :-) Only integral constants can be initialized inline, or otherwise `constexpr`s.

Comment: indeed, in my code, I do not want gravity to be constant. I want the main function to be able to change it if it want to !

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

In your header:

```
struct WC
{
   static const double g;
};
```

In your source file:

```
const double WC::g = 9.81;
```

Please note that anonymous struc and typedef use is C-style, not C++.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you put it into the scope of a class or struct, if it's static it is still a global.

Putting it within a struct would be useful in a meta-programming world, i.e.

```
struct Earth
{
   static const double gravity;
};

struct Mars
{
   static const double gravity;
};

// pseudo code
template< typename PLANET >
someFuncOrClass
{
     using PLANET::gravity;
}
```

This gets resolved at compile time (compared to making Planet a class that has a gravity attribute).

The obvious alternative scoping option though is a namespace.

```
namespace WC
{
     static double gravity;
}
```